# How to ordering middle of the table data in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i have table 'Test' cotains below data

```
col1    col2
----    -----
448      1
448      1
448      1
449      2
449      2
449      2
450      3
```

i need the data in below format

```
col1    col2
----    -----
448      1
449      2
448      1
449      2
448      1
449      2
450      3
```

Comment: On what basis do you need the ordering? It is unclear

Answer (score 2):

You want to distribute the rows.  You can do this by assigning a row number for each group (`col2`) and then sorting on that:

```
select col1, col2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by seqnum, col1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM (
  SELECT col1, col2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) AS rn
  FROM mytable) AS t
ORDER BY rn, col1
```